# xaml image can not positioned to top of carouselview

Tags: xaml, user-interface, mvvm, layout, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms application, i have a CarouselView with images inside it.
I want to position the images inside the CarouselView on the top of the Carousel. i tried with `VerticalOptions="Start"` but it doesn't work.
Here is my Carousel Xaml:

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl
        x:Name="TeaserCarouselView"
        ShowIndicators="true"
        InterPageSpacing="16"
        CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="#4A9630"
        IndicatorsTintColor="#8bdc6f"
        HeightRequest="300"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MainTeaserImageUrls}">
        <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Source="{Binding .}">
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

The images are always in the center of the Carousel. How can i change this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to put the image inside a Grid. The Code above does not change except of the encapsulation of the `ffimageloading` inside a `<Grid>`. Now it works fine!